# Eigenvalues of the $p$-adic Harmonic oscillator?

Tags: number-theory

Given a prime $q$, what are the values of the $p$-adic Harmonic oscillator  that is the solution to the following $p$-adic differential equation?

$$ -D^2_q f(x)+ x_q^2 f(x) = E_n f(x) .$$

What are the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions? For $q=\infty$, the system is the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: There is a school of (mostly Russian) theoretical physicists who work on such things -- look up the papers of E.I. Zelenov and B.G. Dragovich, among others. Frankly, despite being a number theorist working on p-adic automorphic forms, I can't make head or tail of any of it, but perhaps it will mean something to you...

Comment: What exactly are $D_q$ and $x_q$? What kind of function is $f$ and what kind of variable is $x$?

Comment: $ D_{q} $ is the q-adic definition of the derivative for finite prime 'q' $ x_{q} $ is the position of the harmonic oscillator taking only values on $ Q_{q} $ p-adic

Comment: Can explain *the q-adic definition of the derivative for finite prime* a little more? Maybe you show, what you have done so far...